# How to parse JSON using AFNetworking in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking framework in my app, I am able to make HTTP request and able to get response from server but i am not able to parse the JSON.

The following is my code:

I have created a singleton class called WebServices and have created a method, which makes HTTP request.

```
+(void)getCompaniesc:(NSString *)companyID onSucess:(PSACompletionBlock2)onSucess
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"companyId": companyID};

    [[[WebServices sharedInstance] operationQueue] cancelAllOperations];

    [[WebServices sharedInstance] postPath:@"GetCompany?" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response)
     {
         NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response];
         NSLog(@"st=%@",st);

         if (onSucess)
         {
             onSucess(YES, response);
         }


     }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

         NSLog(@"%s: AFHTTPRequestOperation error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
     }];
}
```

and from my `ViewController` I am calling the above function using the following code:

```
[WebServicesClass getCompaniesc:companyID onSucess:^(BOOL success, id jsonresponse) {

}];
```

I'm getting the response from the server which is type `id`.

And the following is my response from Server:

```
[{"ExistsInDB":"False","CanSave":"True","EntityName":"ACCOUNT","TypeDescription":"Company","TypePluralDescription":"Companies","RequiredProperties":"Chiever.Data.SAQueryFieldSet","MetaData":"","ReadOnly":"False","ACCTNAME":"","AREA_ID": "","ACCT_TYPE_ID":"","ADDR1":"","ADDR2":"","ADDR3":"","TOWN”:””,”COUNTY":"","POSTCODE":"","COUNTRY":"","TEL":"","FAX":"","EMAILORWEB":"","BUYGRP_ID": "","STATUS":"","SIC_CODE_ID”:””,”CURRENCY_ID":"","CALL_FREQ": "0","DORMANT":"False","CREATOR_ID": "","CREATED_ON":"01/01/0001 00:00:00","LAST_EDITOR_ID":"","LAST_EDITED":"01/01/0001 00:00:00","LAST_ACTION_BY":"","LAST_ACTION":"01/01/0001 00:00:00","NEXT_ACTION_BY":"","NEXT_ACTION":"01/01/0001 00:00:00","LOCALE_ID":"","BusinessUnits": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[chiever.Platform.LookupIdValuePair]","ACCT_ID":"0000000320"}]
```

Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: Please format your code. Do you get an error / exception? Does the server return correct headers? Have you told AFNetworking to expect JSON?

Comment: i have set the headers:
        [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"]];

Comment: Which version of AFNetworking are you using ?

Comment: 1.0 because the app should support iOS5 and above

Comment: So how are you "not able to parse" the JSON?  Have you tried using a JSON parser??

Comment: How are you setting-up the `WebServicesClass`?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this check:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonresponse options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

if your return is an array, use this:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonresponse options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: Sorry @Nilesh.S.Joshi, I fix my answer. Please, try again!!

Comment: m getting null as NSDictionary

Comment: The outermost layer of the JSON is an array (not that that would cause a null return value).  @Nilesh.S.Joshi - What is the return value in `error`?

Comment: by using this 
NSDictionary* json=(NSDictionary*)response;
i am getting the data in NSDictionary* json.
 in this format:
<227b5c72 5c6e2020 5c224578 69737473 496e4442 5c223a20 5c224661 6c73655c 222c5c72 5c6e2020 5c224361 6e536176 655c223a 205c2254 7275655c>

Comment: @Nilesh.S.Joshi - That appears to be an NSData object. It would need to be parsed with NSJSONSerialization to obtain the NSArray containing the JSON data.

Comment: @Nilesh.S.Joshi I change my answer with an exemplo that Hot Licks spoke!

Answer (score 1):

A.) If you're using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` make sure you're setting the `responseSerializer`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONParserResponseSerializer serializer];
```

Also, make sure that you're setting request "Content-Type" to be "text/json". Now, if you're getting JSON response from the server, then you probably should get a dictionary `responseObject`.

B.) If you're still getting an `NSData`, you can convert the `NSData` to `NSString` to see/debug what you're getting from the server:

```
NSString *stringResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // Use appropriate encoding
NSLog(@"String Response: %@", stringResponse);
```

C.) If you're sure that you're getting json response from the server, you can always convert the raw `NSData` response to `NSDictionary` using json serialization:

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", json);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your server returns the `"Content-Type: application/json"` header, you will get a `NSDictionary` with the json response from AFNetworking. Or in your case, a `NSArray` with NSDictionaries included.

In PHP, the headers can be modified by adding

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

to the top of your script.